# Graphql Filter on sub item

Tags: c#, .net, graphql

I am continuing to try and understand how to use GraphQL. I have a nice enough approach to returning by name, but would now like to only show results where an order made more than one purchase of an item. e.g. in the example below I would like to only return people that have more than one "orderline"

```
query {
  persons(firstname: "Andrew")
  {
    firstname
    surname
    orders {
      id
      totalcost
      orderlines {
        quantity
        product {
          name
          description
          price
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Below is my current query

```
public class PersonQuery : ObjectGraphType<Person>
{
    public PersonQuery(ShoppingData data)
    {
        Field<PersonType>(
            name: "person",
            description: "A Person",
            arguments: new QueryArguments(
                new QueryArgument<IdGraphType>
                {
                    Name = "id",
                    Description = "The id of the person"
                }),
            resolve: ctx =>
            {
                 return data.GetById(ctx.GetArgument<Guid>("id"));
            });

        Field<ListGraphType<PersonType>>(
            name : "persons",
            description: "Persons",
            arguments: new QueryArguments(
                new QueryArgument<StringGraphType>
                {
                    Name = "firstname",
                    Description = "The firstname of the person"
                },
                new QueryArgument<StringGraphType>
                {
                    Name = "surname",
                    Description = "The surname of the person"
                }),
            resolve: ctx =>
            {
                var firstName = ctx.GetArgument<String>("firstname");
                var surname = ctx.GetArgument<String>("surname");
                return data.Filter(firstName, surname);
            });
    }
}
```

1. So my question is how would I write a query to on only returning persons who have ordered more than item e.g. > 1 order lines.
2. How would I write a query to show all the people base on my filter, but then only show orders with more than 1 order line? e.g. so people who only made one order line would be shown, but their order would not be show below that? yet people with more than one order line would see them.

Many thanks

Comment: The answer to this is the same as the answer I gave you yesterday for your other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54443844/graphql-how-would-i-write-a-query-to-find-by-first-name/54443969#54443969

Comment: Hi DavidG, are you saying I should just put arguments against the person level. Is it not possible to add arguments to the orderlines level and hence filter what is show for the order lines?

Comment: Yes, that's GraphQL syntax.